# PHP shebang inappropriate?

Tags: php, shebang

I was going to add a shebang line to a php script

```
#!/bin/env php
```

but I was looking around and people don't seem to be doing this.

- http://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/marketing/about.php
- http://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Cart.php
- http://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php

Is it "inappropriate" or against some rule to shebang a php file?

Comment: why did you want to do it? how is this script run? the only place i have one is for the script that gets mail piped to it.

Comment: I think you mean `#!/usr/bin/env`.  The whole point of that construct is to take advantage of the highly standardised path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually hashbangs are only added when the PHP script is intended to be run from the command line, where it is useful. It is not typically useful to run PHP scripts designed for the web on the command line, and as such, people do not add hashbangs to them.

Also, I believe that in non-CLI PHP environments, PHP will echo the hashbang.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a UNIX shell script the shebang is appropriate. If it's for a webpage it isn't.

Comment: In a sense I suppose that php-cli is acting as a shell, but it's an odd way to say what you apparently mean.  Better to say "If it's to be run from a UNIX command shell the shebang is appropriate"...

Comment: @mc0e "shell script" is a widely-recognized compound noun meaning "a script which is run from a command shell", rather than "a script which provides a shell". So what you wrote is functionally exactly what SpliFF said, but I can understand the confusion.

Comment: @DewiMorgan  I certainly didn't mean "a script which provides a shell".  It would have been better if I had said 'from the unix command line', or 'from a unix interactive shell' instead of 'from a UNIX command shell'.